# Iterating through a list of a custom class

Tags: c++, list, pointers, for-loop, compiler-errors

I'm trying to iterate through a list that contains objects of the type 'Window' (a custom class I wrote).
The for loop is supposed to use the getTitle() method of the Window class on each element and print out the title in the console.

For some reason when I try to access the method through the iterator it tells me the method does not exist..

This is my code:

```
void Center::printWindowList()
{
    for (std::list<Window>::iterator it = windowList.begin(); it != windowList.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it.getTitle();
}
```

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue of operator precedence. Try doing `it->getTitle()` or `(*it).getTitle()`.

Comment: Just tried this, the program compiles now and runs but when stepping through the for loop I get an error message popping up saying "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: list iterators incompatible".. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: That's a separate issue/question. Are you showing all of the code that is relevant to this? Is the type of `windowList` indeed `list<Window>` exactly?

Comment: Yea the type is exactly list<Window> but there's a ton of other code that probably has to do with it since the list takes values from the EnumWindowsProc function of the Windows API. I should probably open a seperate question for it, thanks for the help!